# Python/Selenium fails when script is run through cron, but is fine when script run manually

Tags: python, selenium, cron

Running a Python script using Selenium on a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu Server 22.04. Chromium Browser Chromedriver V 103.0.5060.53 (the current stable via https://chromedriver.chromium.org/)

When I run the script in the terminal, everything works as expected, however when the script executes via a cron job, the script fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/code.py", line 59, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver'), options=chrome_options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

Here is how I am configuring the driver:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('start_maximized')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver'), options=chrome_options)
```

Can't find any troubleshooting for Status code: 1  or assert_process_still_running, so any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same issue. What I have found is that if I update CRONTAB then the next run will be successful, however subsequent runs will fail with status = 1.

Therefore I created a script to auto update the time that my cron job would run, its hacky but it helps.

```
import subprocess # needed for the subprocess.run function
import random # need for the choice function

def listToString (listA,delim = " "):
    result = ""
    for i in listA:
        result = result + str(i) + delim
    return result

# Run crontab
cronProcess = subprocess.run(["crontab", "-l" ], capture_output=True,text=True)

# Set the output from the stdout then split the string by newline
cronList = cronProcess.stdout.split("\n")

#Filter for the job that we want, that is, filter out comments and blank lines
# Return a tuple of the index and the job we want to change the run time for
jobToFind = "nameOfJobToEdit"
cronJobTuple = [(index, job) for index, job in enumerate(cronList) if len(job) > 0 and job[0] != "#"  and job.find(jobToFind) >= 0  ][0]

# Save the index and job info
cronJobIndex = int(cronJobTuple[0])
cronJobStr = cronJobTuple[1]

# Split the cronjob so that the date/times are separate
cronJobList = cronJobStr.split(" ", 5)

# Get the minute/hour values from the cronjob
minuteJobLastRan =  int(cronJobList[0])
hourJobLastRan   =  int(cronJobList[1])

# Remove the previous minute the job last ran
minsInHour = list(range(0,60))
minsInHour.pop(minuteJobLastRan)
minuteToRunJobList = minsInHour

# Remove the previous hour the job last ran
hoursInDay = list(range(0,23))
hoursInDay.pop(hourJobLastRan)
hourToRunJobList = hoursInDay

# Select a random minute/hour to run the new job
cronJobList[0] = random.choice(minuteToRunJobList)
cronJobList[1] = random.choice(hourToRunJobList)

# Convert the job back to a string
modifiedCronJobStr = listToString(cronJobList)

# Update the cronTab with the modified job
cronList[cronJobIndex] = modifiedCronJobStr

#Convert the entire cronTab back to a string
cronStr = listToString(cronList,delim="\n")

# Save the string to file
#open text file
file_name = "tmpCronFile.txt"
text_file = open(file_name, "w")
#write string to file
n = text_file.write(cronStr)    
#close file
text_file.close()
print("Status code of write is [{}]".format(n))

# Update crontab
subprocess.run(["crontab", file_name ], capture_output=True,text=True)

# Delete temp file
subprocess.run(["rm", file_name ], capture_output=True,text=True
```

I then created it as an entry to the cronTab and it updates cronTab every midnight

```
#m  h   dom  mon dow  command
0 0 * * * python $HOME/cronExecutionTimeRandomiser/cronExecutionTimeRandomiser.py > $HOME/log/cronExecutionTimeRandomiser`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`.log 2>&1
```